# Any idea how to make a Drupal 8 route be loaded when a Drupal 7 one is called?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal

I've and old Drupal 7 site in drupal7.mysite.com hosted in an amazon machine. The idea is start developing in parallel a new site with Drupal 8 in the same machine and deploy it step by step.

First step is create a landing page in Drupal 8 and that landing responses at drupal7.mysite.com/landing-page maintaining that url in browser.

I've tried to use several options:

- Create the Drupal 8 project inside Drupal 7 directory and use an Apache Alias in drupal7.mysite.com.conf virtualhost.

```bash
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName drupal7.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/web/drupal7/
        Alias /drupal8 "/var/www/web/drupal7/drupal8/web/"
        <Directory "/var/www/web/drupal7/">
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from All
                <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                        Options -MultiViews
                        RewriteEngine On
                        Require all granted
                </IfModule>
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myerros.log
</VirtualHost>
```

- Use Rewrite rules in .htaccess

```bash
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond         "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/landing/%{REQUEST_URI}"  -f
  RewriteRule "^(.+)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/landing/$1"  [L]
  RewriteCond         "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/drupal8/landing_page/%{REQUEST_URI}"  -f
  RewriteRule "^(.+)" "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/drupal8/landing_page/$1"  [L]
  RewriteRule "^"     "-"                                          [PT]
```

Using previous both together or separate I don't reach a good result. Someone have a better idea?

Thanks :)

**Update 1:**

Finally I've tried with this dir structure:

```
var/
|_www/
  |_html/
     |_drupal7 (Drupal 7 web folder)
        |
        |-.htaccess (Drupal 7 .htaccess)
        |-index.php (Drupal 7 index)
        |
        |-web/ (Drupal 8 web folder)
            |
            |-index.php (Drupal 8 index)
```

VirtualHost definition is:

```bash
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName drupal7.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/drupal7/
        <Directory "/var/www/html/drupal7/">
                AllowOverride All
                Allow from All
                <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
                        Options -MultiViews
                        RewriteEngine On
                        Require all granted
                </IfModule>
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/myerrors.log
</VirtualHost>
```

And added this line to the .htaccess:

```bash
Redirect 301 /landing https://drupal7.mysite.com/web/landing-page
```

So that works fine. URL *https://drupal7.mysite/landing* is redirected to drupal 8 route *https://drupal7.mysite.com/web/landing-page*. ¿Problem? Users can see the route change. I need something like this internal redirection https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/remapping.html#old-to-new

Comment: Not sure that I understood you well - you want drupal 7 and drupal 8 sites working together on the same domain?

Comment: Yep. I'm trying to find a kind of live migration from old drupal 7 nodes to new drupal 8 ones with a cheap solution without a reverse proxy to dispatch between drupals.

Comment: Not sure that 2 sites can work together on the same domain. At least it won't be easy to achieve.

Comment: By amazon machine, do you mean an EC2 instance? I think the most straight-forward solution is to create another EC2 instance to host the D8 site. Then, redirecting requests from the main D7 site to D8 will require less custom configuration. And imagine the day when you're done migrating, you just turn off the EC2 box with D7. Much easier to manage, test, and verify.